# Compilation warning due to mismatch in function pointer type definition and assigned function with correct const logic

Tags: c++, c, api, pointers, constants

I am using an external library in a project that I am working on. It is written in C. In the external library, the following is defined:

```
typedef void* (*foo_fn) (void *arg1, void *arg2);
```

One of library's API/function takes the function pointer (of the above type) as input.

Now, in my module, I am implementing a function as mentioned below, as I know that would make more sense for this function's logic:

```
void * foo_fn (const void* const arg1, void* const arg2);
```

When I pass in this function's pointer to the API, I get the following warning:

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

I understand the reason behind the above warning, but I would like to know which of the following is the right thing to do?

1. Define the function like above and ignore the warning.
2. "Strictly adhere" to the external library's expectation and ignore the logic that would make sense for my function and define the function as below?

   ```
   void * foo_fn (void* arg1, void* arg2);
   ```

Comment: Is is possible to write a function with the API's signature that calls your function with the desired signature?

Comment: That should be doable. So, can I consider it is a good practice to not leave behind any compilation warnings even though I know it is not "harmful" one like the above mentioned scenario?

Comment: Typically, you want your compiler warning level to be set high and you don't want to produce any warnings.  The reason for this is that as your code base grows a few warnings will grow into a few more until you have many warnings.  As other developers work with your code they won't know if the warnings are "real" or just previously ignored warnings.

Comment: Are you compiling as C or C++?

Answer (score 2):

Even though the function conforms to the required signature under computer-science notions of the LSP, the pointer is adding a `const`-qualification (which is safe), and the pointer types are strictly required to be representation- and layout-compatible (this is implied by being able to store `&px` where `X* px;` in a variable of type `const X* const* const`, which is legal), in C++ the function pointer types are different and calling through a function pointer of wrong type is **undefined behavior**.

This is important because it gives the optimizer special permission to break code that does this, even though a naive (unoptimized) compilation would generate working code on any architecture.

For example, if there's only one function in the entire program of the type that actual matches the function pointer, the optimizer could create a direct call to that function (or even inline it), ignoring the address actually in the function pointer.  (Platforms which allow dynamic loading complicate this, but in some cases use of types with local linkage could exclude dynamically loaded functions from matching the signature)

Answer (score 0):

If the library expects a callback with `arg1` of type `void*`, then passing a callback with a parameter of type `const void*` is permissible—your callback makes the extra guarantee of not modifying its input, but the library doesn’t care either way.

So you have two options: safely define `foo_fn` with `const` qualification and give the library a function without `const` that calls the `const` version:

```
void* foo_fn(const void* const arg1, void* arg2);

void* foo_fn_non_const(void* arg1, void* arg2) {
    return foo_fn(arg1, arg2);
}

library_fn(foo_fn_non_const);
```

Or unsafely cast the function pointer type:

```
library_fn(reinterpret_cast<void* (*)(void*, void*)>(foo_fn));
```

This makes one mildly unsafe assumption: that `const void*` has the same calling convention as `void*`.

Comment: As I explain in my answer, `const void*` does necessarily have the same representation as `void*`.  However, that assumption isn't sufficient.